# ServiceWorker WindowClient.navigate promise rejected

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging + Service worker to handle background push notifications.

When the notification (which contains some data + a URL) is clicked, I want to either:

- Focus the window if it's already on the desired URL
- Navigate to the URL and focus it if there is already an active tab open
- Open a new window to the URL if neither of the above conditions are met

Points 1 and 3 work with the below SW code.

For some reason point #2 isn't working. The `client.navigate()` promise is being rejected with:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot navigate to URL: http://localhost:4200/tasks/-KMcCHZdQ2YKCgTA4ddd`

I thought it might be due to a lack of https, but from my reading it appears as though localhost is whitelisted while developing with SW.

firebase-messaging-sw.js:

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.3/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.3/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'XXXX'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(payload => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  let notificationData = JSON.parse(payload.data.notification);
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: notificationData.body,
    data: {
      clickUrl: notificationData.clickUrl
    }
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationData.title,
    notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Notification OnClick: ', event);

  // Android doesn’t close the notification when you click on it
  // See: http://crbug.com/463146
  event.notification.close();

  // This looks to see if the current is already open and
  // focuses if it is
  event.notification.close();
  let validUrls = /localhost:4200/;
  let newUrl = event.notification.data.clickUrl || '';

  function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
  }

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({
      includeUncontrolled: true,
      type: 'window'
    })
    .then(windowClients => {
      for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
        let client = windowClients[i];
        if (validUrls.test(client.url) && 'focus' in client) {
          if (endsWith(client.url, newUrl)) {
            console.log('URL already open, focusing.');
            return client.focus();
          } else {
            console.log('Navigate to URL and focus', client.url, newUrl);
            return client.navigate(newUrl).then(client => client.focus());
          }
        }
      }

      if (clients.openWindow) {
        console.log('Opening new window', newUrl);
        return clients.openWindow(newUrl);
      }
    })
  );

});
```

The vast majority of my SW code is taken from:
https://gist.github.com/vibgy/0c5f51a8c5756a5c408da214da5aa7b0

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend leaving out `includeUncontrolled: true` from your `clients.matchAll()`.

The `WindowClient` that you're acting on might not have the current service worker as its active service worker. As per item 4 in [the specification for `WindowClient.navigate()`](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#dom-windowclient-navigate):

> If the context object’s associated service worker client’s active
>   service worker is not the context object’s relevant global object’s
>   service worker, return a promise rejected with a `TypeError`.

If you can reproduce the issue when you're sure the client is currently controlled by the service worker, then there might be something else going on, but that's what I'd try as a first step.

Comment: To further Jeff's comment, the firebase-messaging-sw.js will *definitely* not be controlling page, this is by design. If you want this behavior, you can pass a custom service worker registration into `messaging.useServiceWorker(<your registration here>)`. This service worker registration could control all pages on your origin and would allow use of the navigate() call.

Comment: @Jeff - I was finding that `clients.matchAll()` was not returning any WindowClients unless I included uncontrolled windows, which makes sense given what @Gaunt just mentioned.

Thank you both for the suggestions, I will let you know how this goes, and likely mark this as the accepted answer once I get it working.

Comment: @GauntFace could you elaborate on this? I've passed my own serviceworker to messaging.useServiceWorker but get the same error.

Comment: Please open a new issue with example file locations, file contents and error messages you are getting.

Comment: @rabhw did you get a solution to this problem, we are facing a similar situation, it works in firefox but gives a similar error in Chrome browser. Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: @Jeff Posnick to be more specific we are getting the Type Error you have mentioned in your answer, but excluding the `includeUncontrolled: true` does not return the already open window which results in opening a new window every time. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

**1- create an observable and make sure not to call the messaging API before it resolves.**

**2- register the service worker yourself, and check first if its already registered**

**3- call event.waitUntil(clients.claim()); in your service worker**

```
private isMessagingInitialized$: Subject<void>;

constructor(private firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('/').then(registration => {
        if (registration) {
            // optionally update your service worker to the latest firebase-messaging-sw.js
            registration.update().then(() => { 
                firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp).useServiceWorker(registration);
                this.isMessagingInitialized$.next();
            });
        }
        else {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope:'/'}).then(
                registration => {
                    firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp).useServiceWorker(registration);
                    this.isMessagingInitialized$.next();
                }
            );

        }
    });
    
    this.isMessagingInitialized$.subscribe(
        () => {
            firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp).usePublicVapidKey('Your public api key');
            firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp).onTokenRefresh(() => {
                this.getToken().subscribe((token: string) => {

                })
            });
            firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp).onMessage((payload: any) => {

            });
        }
    );
}
```

- firebase-messaging-sw.js

  ```
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {

    event.notification.close();

    switch (event.action) {
        case 'close': {
            break;
        }
        default: {
            event.waitUntil(clients.claim());// this 
            event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
                includeUncontrolled: true,
                type: "window"
            }).then(function (clientList) {
            ...
            clientList[i].navigate('you url');
            ...
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  }